Why is there no article after 'by'?
In the book English Grammar in Use, unit 128,  I read this.

Note that we say by chance, by accident etc. (not by the chance / by an accident).  In these expressions, we use by + noun without the or a.

Is there any logic, or must I remember that as a rule?

There is no logic, it's 'just the way we say it'. However, if the noun is qualified by an adjective we do use the indefinite article - "By a strange chance", "By a fortunate accident" etc.

Adding to Kate's observation, the indefinite article is included with prepositional phrases as post-qualifiers also, whether they are closely (He became President by an accident of history) (possibly a complement here?) or more loosely (injuries caused by an accident at work) (an adjunct) associated with the noun.

An article makes a "by" statement seem more specific. "I like to fish by moonlight" is general, and might just be referring to a time of day. "I like to fish by the moonlight" suggests that the quality of the light is important. I also think leaving out the article is poetic in a way, condensing speech into turns of phrase.

The preposition by is often used without a determiner. Here are some other examples:

done by mistake
travelled by car
made by hand
finished by autumn
working by night

It is often used with a determiner, though:

sitting by the river
written by the author

I think we use by with a preposition when we are talking about a specific thing that is important to the understanding of the sentence, and without a preposition when we only need to explain in general terms about something.

The package was delivered to me by mistake - general
The accident was caused by a mistake on the part of the driver - specific
The driver made a mistake. The accident was caused by the mistake - specific


Thank you! That's a very useful and clear answer. Now I understand how it works:)

Did you mean "written about by the author"?

@traktor "sitting by the river written by the author" was intended to be two examples but they were merged into one by the formatting. As a standalone phrase, "written by the author" does not need "about."

Some idioms and phrases with by take an article and some don't. You'll have to learn each, but it's not too difficult, because they are fairly common.
Examples:

by chance = accidentally
by mistake, by error = mistakenly
by and large = everything considered
by heart = from memory
by hook or by crook = by any possible means
by magic/as if by magic = by the power of magic
by golly, by gosh, by Jove/jove = used to express surprise
by force =  using physical power
by appointment = by agreement as to place and time
by/from all accounts = according to reports, descriptions
by far = by a great amount
by necessity = because conditions can't be changed
by all means = without hesitation or doubt
by no means  = in no way; certainly not
by way of = via
by dint of = because of; by force of



by a nose = by a very narrow margin (as in a race)
by a hair = very narrowly
by a long shot = by a great amount
by some distance = by a great extent
by the way = used to introduce a new subject
by the book = strictly following the rules
by the rules = the accepted, expected way
by a/some miracle = surprisingly; amazingly
fall by the wayside = stop before completion
by the day = as each day passes
by the by = incidentally
by a landslide = by a very big margin (esp. in an election)
by the boatload/score = in large numbers
by any means necessary = doing whatever is needed
not by any means = not at all; in no way
by the time = when; at the time


'By and large'  extragrammatical, as are arguably 'by golly' and 'by the by' (the nouns have been mangled here). Nice list.

I'd class 'idioms' as a subset (or two) of 'fixed expressions': fixed expressions with (a) atypical sense of word/s and/or (b) atypical grammar.

@EdwinAshworth in theory yes, but dictionaries often don't agree on any one item--some will label it an idiom, others a phrase. M-W labels by force as an idiom, which is why I included it. However, I don't see how it differs from by stealth / cunning / trickery / persuasion, etc. By here meaning by means of.

I remember both John Lawler and BillJ decrying many of the grammatical pronouncements / classifications made by dictionaries.

By chance is a phrase, as defined in Collins Dictionary sense B1:

Something that happens by chance was not planned by anyone.


He had met Mr Maude by chance.

By accident is an idiom, as defined in Cambridge Dictionary sense B1:

without intending to, or without being intended:


I deleted the file by accident.


It's interesting that CD classes 'by accident' as an idiom but 'by chance' as a collocation. I can't see their logic. There seems little difference in their idiomaticity (ie frequency of use) according to their Google 2-grams. And little difference in semanto-syntactical structure.

Thanks, @Edwin Ashworth.  The lines may not always be clear.
Oxford Research Encyclopedias gives a list of different forms and their differences.

Thank you for that. A fascinating reference. I'm reasonably familiar with Moon's monumental treatise 'Fixed Expressions and Idioms ...'; the only fault I could find was that 'Fixed Expressions including Idioms ...' would be more accurate. // But both 'by chance' and 'by accident'  are not totally predictable by a general rule  ('by luck' is idiomatic, 'by fortune' is iffy, but 'by serendipity' sounds ridiculous) and the preposition is not used prototypically) so I'd class them both as extragrammatical idioms. // The number of different analyses (and the meta-analyses) proves your assertion.

'By chance' and 'By accident' are collocations. A collocation is a group of two or more words that are almost always put together to create a specific meaning. we use them the way they are created. It's just the way we use them.

There's an argument that these are rather colligations, as at least slightly unusual grammar is involved ('by serendipity', standalone 'by fate'  are not available_).

The word "by" have a variety of meanings and use cases. In your examples, the "by" should be followed by a noun, just as indicated. The reason for this is probably because we are referring to a type of event, instead of a specific event, as may be interpreted if we use "the" or "a". However, this is just a possibility, and there always exists the possibility that people simply got lax in the article part. In any case, the "fluent" way of saying this is without the article.
